# How many years can I get on a Canadian tourist visa?

Tags: visas, canada, tourist-visas, canadian-citizens

I am visiting the US on a B1 visa for two months. I am planning to visit Canada on a tourist visa. I looked at the [process](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/apply-how.asp) but they haven't mentioned anywhere whether it is single- or double-entry. Also, how many years can I visit Canada on this visa? Like on a US B1 visa I can visit multiple times and it will expire in 10 years from the date of issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All applicants for Canadian temporary resident visas (e.g. tourism, business or transit) are [automatically considered for multiple-entry visas](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=417&top=16), even if they select single entry on their application.

> Starting on February 6, 2014 (00:01 EST), all visa applicants will automatically be considered for a multiple entry visa. The visa officer reviewing your application may be able to give you this type of visa even if you applied for a single entry visa.

Whether you get the multiple entry visa, and the duration of validity of the visa, [depends on your personal circumstances](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/media/backgrounders/2011/2011-07-20.asp). You may receive a visa valid for up to 10 years or one month before your passport expiration date, whichever comes first. (So, if your passport is near to expiration, you should renew it before applying for a visa to Canada.)

> Not everyone who applies for a multiple entry visa is issued one. Applications are examined on a case-by-case basis and must take into consideration the fee paid (single- or multiple-entry) in addition to the assessed risk of the individual applying. Officers are now encouraged to issue multiple entry visas to the maximum duration of the validity of the passport.